# SQLite and MySQL order by clause difference

Tags: iphone, mysql, sqlite

I am having a trouble dealing with Databases in iPhone app. The order by clause of SQLite and MySQL returns records in different order. I am ordering the records on basis of date entered field of records. Queries of MYSQL and SQlite returns the same records but in different order when multiple records have same date entered value. Any possible solution to get same order from SQLite query in iPhone as that of MYSQL query result.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to disambiguate the order by using another column:

```
... ORDER BY date, id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just choose a second column to order.

Comment: i cannot perform this as its not there is no second sort element on server side. I have to sort on one coloumn.

Comment: Maybe I missing something... You have said that multiple records with same date are ordering different. If the records have same date and are different then there are more than one column. ?!

Comment: Yes there are plenty of colums in that table, but i cannot add a second sorter in my query as if i change sorting query on iphone side then it must be changed on server side to have same records but i am unable to change query on server side. Thats why i am avoiding a second sorter.